# What are the Function types

Tags: haskell

The question is to determine function type of this : second xs = head (tail xs)

I tried everything

:t second gives me:

```
*Main> :type second
second :: [a] -> a --- is this the function type?
```

,then I tried :type second; :type "second xs = head (tail xs)".

It still does not work. How to determine Function type using Haskell

Comment: What do you mean by *"it does not work"*? What error did you get? Did you actually define `second` before trying to find its type? Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: *Main> :type second
second :: [a] -> a

Comment: You have not explained anything with this comment. Again, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54300271/edit) to add relevant information such as what errors or problems arise, and the full code you typed in to GHCi.

Comment: "is this the function type?" Yes.  It's the function type.

Answer (score 2):

As you already know, you can use GHCi to find the type of a Haskell identifier by using the `:type` command (or its shorter version `:t`). In this case, GHCi gives you the answer `second :: [a] -> a`. The `::` symbol means 'type-of', so this answer is just GHCi's way of telling you that 'the type of `second` is `[a] -> a`'.

But there's still another question here: what does this type mean? Well, let's pull it apart:

- Any type of the form `x -> y` is the type of a function which takes as input one parameter of type `x`, and returns a value of type `y`.
- In this case, we have a type `[a] -> a`, so the input type is `[a]` (i.e. a list of values of type `a`), and the output type is `a` (i.e. a single value of type `a`).
- Thus, the statement `second :: [a] -> a` means that `second` is a function which takes as input a list of `a`s, and gives as output a single value of the same type `a`. This ties in with what we know of the function: given a list, it returns a single value from that list.

**EDIT:** As @chepner pointed out in the comments, it is important to realise that `a` is a stand-in for *any* type. The only constraint is that, if the input is a list of `a`s, then - no matter what `a` is - the return type must also be of type `a`. (This sort of indeterminate type is called a *type variable*.)

Comment: For completeness, note that the type variable `a` represents any single type, without any constraints on what that type might be. The return type, however, must be the same as whatever type of list you started with. (Given `[Int]`, you'll get back an `Int`; given `[Char]`, you'll get back a `Char`, etc.)

Comment: Yes, that's a very good point. Can I edit it in for completeness?

Comment: By all means, please do